# Как отправить рейтинг приложения в кастомном запросе

Tags: ios, swift

Имеется окно которое отправляет пользователя на выбор рейтинга приложения.

Через `UIApplication.shared.open(url)`

Могу ли я как-нибудь передать в запрос рейтинг (от одного до пяти), по умолчания он отображает 5 звезд, возможно ли это как-то изменить.

Сразу прошу решения связанные с `SKStoreReviewController` не предлагать.